# Arduino to Raspberry crc32 check

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, crc32

I'm trying to send messages through the serial USB interface of my Arduino (C++) to a Raspberry Pi (Python).

On the Arduino side I define a struct which I then copy into a char[]. The last part of the struct contains a checksum that I want to calculate using CRC32. I copy the struct into a temporary char array -4 bytes to strip the checksum field. The checksum is then calculated using the temporary array and the result is added to the struct. The struct is then copied into byteMsg which gets send over the serial connection.

On the raspberry end I do the reverse, I receive the bytestring and calculate the checksum over the message - 4 bytes. Then unpack the bytestring and compare the received and calculated checksum but this fails unfortunately.

For debugging I compared the crc32 check on both the python and arduino for the string "Hello World" and they generated the same checksum so doesn't seem to be a problem with the library. The raspberry is also able to decode the rest of the message just fine so the unpacking of the data into variables seem to be ok as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The Python Code:

```
   def unpackMessage(self, message):
        """ Processes a received byte string from the arduino """

        # Unpack the received message into struct
        (messageID, acknowledgeID, module, commandType,
         data, recvChecksum) = struct.unpack('<LLBBLL', message)

        # Calculate the checksum of the recv message minus the last 4
        # bytes that contain the sent checksum
        calcChecksum = crc32(message[:-4])
        if recvChecksum == calcChecksum:
            print "Checksum checks out"
```

The Aruino crc32 library taken from http://excamera.com/sphinx/article-crc.html

crc32.h

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

static PROGMEM prog_uint32_t crc_table[16] = {
    0x00000000, 0x1db71064, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac,
    0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158, 0x5005713c,
    0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
    0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c
};

unsigned long crc_update(unsigned long crc, byte data)
{
    byte tbl_idx;
    tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (0 * 4));
    crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + (tbl_idx & 0x0f)) ^ (crc >> 4);
    tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (1 * 4));
    crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + (tbl_idx & 0x0f)) ^ (crc >> 4);
    return crc;
}

unsigned long crc_string(char *s)
{
  unsigned long crc = ~0L;
  while (*s)
    crc = crc_update(crc, *s++);
  crc = ~crc;
  return crc;
}
```

Main Arduino Sketch

```
struct message_t {
    unsigned long messageID;
    unsigned long acknowledgeID;
    byte module;
    byte commandType;
    unsigned long data;
    unsigned long checksum;
};

void sendMessage(message_t &msg)
{
    // Set the messageID
    msg.messageID = 10;
    msg.checksum = 0;

    // Copy the message minus the checksum into a char*
    // Then perform the checksum on the message and copy
    // the full msg into byteMsg
    char byteMsgForCrc32[sizeof(msg)-4];
    memcpy(byteMsgForCrc32, &msg, sizeof(msg)-4);
    msg.checksum = crc_string(byteMsgForCrc32);

    char byteMsg[sizeof(msg)];
    memcpy(byteMsg, &msg, sizeof(msg));

    Serial.write(byteMsg, sizeof(byteMsg));

void loop() {
    message_t msg;
    msg.module = 0x31;
    msg.commandType = 0x64;
    msg.acknowledgeID = 0;
    msg.data = 10;

    sendMessage(msg);
```

Kind Regards,
Thiezn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the classic struct-to-network/serial/insert communication layer mistake. Structs have hidden padding in order to align the members onto suitable memory boundaries. This is not guaranteed to be the same across different computers, let alone different CPUs/microcontrollers.

Take this struct as an example:

```
struct Byte_Int
{
     int x;
     char y;
     int z;
}
```

Now on a basic 32-bit x86 CPU you have a 4-byte memory boundary. Meaning that variables are aligned to either 4 bytes, 2 bytes or not at all according to the type of variable. The example would look like this in memory: int x on bytes 0,1,2,3, char y on byte 4, int z on bytes 8,9,10,11. Why not use the three bytes on the second line? Because then the memory controller would have to do two fetches to get a single number! A controller can only read one line at a time. So, structs (and all other kinds of data) have hidden padding in order to get variables aligned in memory. The example struct would have a sizeof() of 12, and not 9!

Now, how does that relate to your problem? You are memcpy()ing a struct directly into a buffer, including the padding. The computer on the other end doesn't know about this padding and misinterprets the data. What you need a serialization function that takes the members of your structs and pasts them into a buffer one at a time, that way you lose the padding and end up with something like this:
[0,1,2,3: int x][4: char y][5,6,7,8: int z]. All as one lengthy bytearray/string which can be safely sent using Serial(). Of course on the other end you would have to parse this string into intelligible data. Python's unpack() does this for you as long as you give the right format string.

Lastly, an int on an Arduino is 16 bits long. On a pc generally 4! So assemble your unpack format string with care.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! A clear explanation and will implement it tonight and report back my results

Comment: I've tried serializing the struct (taking each element and copying them into a char* but the result was the same size (18 bytes in this case). I noticed that sometimes I was getting a checksum result of 0 whilst I was definitely filling the struct with data. This gave me a hunch that the crc32 function is quitting when it finds a NULL '\0' character in the string and after some tests its seems thats indeed the case. Now I have to admit the crc32 function is a bit out of my league, would someone know how to get it to process NULL terminated characters as well?

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the crc_string() I noticed your while( *s ).  Now a '\0' is indeed a 0 so your loop *will* stop whenever it encounters one. That's the downside of using a string rather than a byte array! The solution is thus to stop treating it as a string. Don't check for ( *s ) but pass along the length of your 'string' and run a for loop based on this length.

Lastly: a CRC of 0 is perfectly valid. It's all really just adding and shifting bits so you can end up with a 0 in the end. Especially with shorter CRCs that can overflow more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The char array I was passing to the crc_string function contained '\0' characters. The crc_string was iterating through the array until it found a '\0' which shouldn't happen in this case since I was using the char array as a stream of bytes to be sent over a serial connection.

I've changed the crc_string function to take the array size as argument and iterate through the array using that value. This solved the issue.

Here's the new function

```
unsigned long crc_string(char *s, size_t arraySize) 
{ 
  unsigned long crc = ~0L; 
  for (int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) { 
    crc = crc_update(crc, s[i]); 
  } 
  crc = ~crc; 
  return crc; 
}
```